# Load C# assembly in C/C++ mscoree.tlh errors

Tags: c++

I wanted to load a C# assembly in a C/C++ project because native loaders seem cool to me but there is a problem with `mscorlib.tlh`. First of all, I'm following codeproject [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607352/Injecting-NET-Assemblies-Into-Unmanaged-Processes) (first snippet). I created an empty C++ project and at first point it didn't seem to find `mscorlib.tlb` but then after changing SDK versions/Platform Toolsets, it however found it but there are some errors.

Current settings:

Windows SDK version: 10.0.17763.0

Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2017 (v141)

Errors:

```
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12974): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '||'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12974): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '||'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12974): error C2059: syntax error: '||'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12974): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12974): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12977): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '||'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12977): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '||'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12977): error C2059: syntax error: '||'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12977): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>c:\users\admin\desktop\netloader\netloader\debug\mscorlib.tlh(12977): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>Done building project "NETLoader.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Screenshot:

[image: errors]

I don't know what's wrong with mscorlib in the latest SDK. There are other unanswered related threads as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It was because `mscorlib.tlh` used `or` for a variable name. All I did was I added [auto_rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/auto-rename?view=vs-2019) while importing mscorlib.tlb.

```
#import "mscorlib.tlb" auto_rename
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/voxsoftware/jxshell.dotnet4/blob/master/ClrHost/ClrHost.cpp

The project is designed for be consumed in VFP via DLL, but can give you an idea how load CLR from c++

Look the important parts: ClrLoad:

```cpp
void WINAPI ClrLoad()
{
    if (ClrVersion.Length() >= 2 && ClrVersion[0] == 'v' && ClrVersion[1] == '2') {
        ClrLoadLegacyVersion2();
        return;
    }

    // Tutorial on how this works: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0
    VerifyHresult(CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMetaHost)));
    VerifyHresult(pMetaHost->GetRuntime(ClrVersion, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo)));
    BOOL fLoadable;
    VerifyHresult(pRuntimeInfo->IsLoadable(&fLoadable));
    if (!fLoadable) throw HresultException("CLR is not loadable.");
    VerifyHresult(pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CorRuntimeHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&spRuntimeHost)));
    VerifyHresult(spRuntimeHost->Start());
    CComPtr<IUnknown> spAppDomainThunk;
    VerifyHresult(spRuntimeHost->GetDefaultDomain(&spAppDomainThunk));
    VerifyHresult(spAppDomainThunk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spDefAppDomain)));
```

And after ClrLoad, load an assembly from disk:

```cpp
/// *** Creates an instance of a class from an assembly referenced through its disk path
IDispatch* WINAPI ClrCreateInstanceFrom(char *AssemblyFileName, char *className, char *ErrorMessage, DWORD *dwErrorSize)
{
    try {
        if (!spDefAppDomain)
            ClrLoad();
        CComPtr<_ObjectHandle> spObjectHandle;
        VerifyHresult(spDefAppDomain->CreateInstanceFrom(_bstr_t(AssemblyFileName), _bstr_t(className), &spObjectHandle));
        CComVariant VntUnwrapped;
        VerifyHresult(spObjectHandle->Unwrap(&VntUnwrapped));
        return VntUnwrapped.pdispVal;
    } catch (HresultException ex) {
        *dwErrorSize = ex.GetMessage(ErrorMessage);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the code but that ``mscorlib.tlh`` gives those errors. I also checked code from MSDN.

Comment: I understand you, but the code that I posted i know that works (i used on my project). You can take as reference for write your  code, loading assembly from c++